# Redeploy safe with same address on OP

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, etherscan, gnosis-safe, safe-core

I deployed the Safe on Ethereum using this factory: 0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2. Now, I'd like to deploy the same Safe address on Optimism. Could you please provide guidance on the necessary steps to achieve this? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

dev

Since Safe's deployment addresses are deterministic you should be able to deploy a safe on Optimism with the same address by using the same exact parameters you used to deploy the one on Ethereum.

Hope this helps

Comment: it didn't work for me. It's generating a different address. Could the use of a different factory address be causing this issue?

Comment: Yes, using a different factory address is definitely an issue. It should be the same, and the same parameters each time (including salt).