# Send DAI on polygon on a SAFE Optimism smart contract wallet

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe, safe

i send some dai polygon on a smart contract SAFE Optimism.

Can someone help me pls i can pay a dev if he find me the solution. Thats not the same proxy so some people said its not possible. thanks

Comment: Maybe you can find the solution here https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover

Answer (score 0):

Are you the owner of this Safe on Optimism? If yes, the solution in this case would be to redeploy a safe at the exact same address than the one on Optimism but on Polygon. Have you tried following [this](https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover) tutorial? There are also a few of questions on stack exchange that treat that subject:

- [Problem with Safe Wallet - Gnosis Safe Account send funds to Polygon to same wallet address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/158764/problem-with-safe-wallet-gnosis-safe-account-send-funds-to-polygon-to-same-wal/158787?noredirect=1#comment173871_158787)
- [Redeploy safe with same address on OP](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/156971/redeploy-safe-with-same-address-on-op/157070#157070)
- [Sent assets on Ethereum to a zkSync Safe address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/158653/sent-assets-on-ethereum-to-a-zksync-safe-address/158776#158776)

Hope it helps!
Louis